# cd command to a variable containing a path with spaces gives different output than actually giving the path as an input

Tags: bash, command-line, cd-command, variable-substitution

I have a directory named "test 1" and I create a variable

```
dest="test\ 1"
```

I want to navigate to the directory using the cd command, so I type

```
cd $dest
```

which gives the output as

```
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

while typing

```
cd test\ 1
```

actually works and changes the current directory to "test 1".

Now, I've read a few other questions and know that I've to type in

```
cd "$dest"
```

for it to work but I don't understand the reason why. Because $dest will basically substitute the value of the variable dest which is nothing but test\ 1. So why does this not work?

Comment: “Because $dest will basically substitute the value of the variable dest” No, it does more than that.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' but since I'm using a backslash, why doesn't it escape the space? Why does it treat test\ and 1 as 2 separate arguments?

Comment: You can see the magic when using `set -x`: What `bash` actually performs is `cd 'test\' 1`.

Comment: Because the backslash is not a special character unless there's also one of `*?[`. `dest='test\ [1]'; cd $test` would work. But of course `cd "$dest"` would not work. And `name='monthly report.txt'; file=$dest/$name; open "$file"` would not work, and wouldn't work with `open $file` either since `$file` would contain a mix of a file name and a wildcard pattern.

Comment: Does backslash actually escape the 'space' character? I mean if I run `echo "Hello \\"` the output is `Hello \\`. This means that the second backslash I added was used as an escape character. But if I run `echo "Hello\ K"`, the output is `Hello\ K`. Why isn't the backslash omitted in the output this time?

Comment: Ignore the '`' above, the code formatting is messed up for some reason.